Relation "schema.table" does not exist Hibernate Spatial Postgis test container
I have added a Geometry type column to my Postgres database, and when I run my quarkus project it works fine, POST/GET methods execute successfully. But when I run build, it fails with message

relation "schema.table" does not exist

build.grade:
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.6.15.Final'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.19.7'

PostgresResource.java:
public class PostgresResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    static DockerImageName image = DockerImageName.parse("postgis/postgis:12-3.0")
        .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres");
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(image)
        .withDatabaseName("somedbname")
        .withUsername("somedbuser")
        .withPassword("password");

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void dumpDb() {

        postgresContainer.execInContainer(
            "pg_dump",
            "-U", "somedbuser",
            "-w", "-Fc",
            "-d", "somedbname",
            "-f", "/tmp/backup"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

        postgresContainer.close();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void restoreDump() {

        postgresContainer
            .execInContainer("pg_restore",
                "-U", "somedbuser", "--clean",
                "-w", "--disable-triggers",
                "--dbname=somedbname",
                "/tmp/backup");
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Map<String, String> start() {

        postgresContainer.start();

        return Map.of(
            "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url", postgresContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
            "quarkus.datasource.username", postgresContainer.getUsername(),
            "quarkus.datasource.password", postgresContainer.getPassword()
        );
    }
}

application.properties:
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=ch.myapp.application.settings.PostgisPG10CustomDialect

PostgisPG10CustomDialect.java:
public class PostgisPG10CustomDialect extends PostgisPG10Dialect {

    public PostgisPG10CustomDialect() {

        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(2003, ListArrayType.class.getName());
    }
}

Field in my entity:
    @Column(name = "polygon_coordinates")
    private Polygon coordinates;

Logs:
    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
    ERROR: relation "shipment.shipment" does not exist
      Position: 1065
    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
    ERROR: relation "shipment.shipment" does not exist
      Position: 1056
    relation "shipment.shipment" does not exist
    
    Error occurred while executing task for trigger %s
    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:332)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:347)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:874)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2357)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$MinimalStage.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2948)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DefaultInvoker.invoke(DefaultInvoker.java:24)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.StatusEmitterInvoker.invoke(StatusEmitterInvoker.java:35)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.SkipConcurrentExecutionInvoker.invoke(SkipConcurrentExecutionInvoker.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask.doInvoke(SimpleScheduler.java:333)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask$1.handle(SimpleScheduler.java:314)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask$1.handle(SimpleScheduler.java:310)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$null$0(ContextBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextBase.java:135)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:581)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

What am I doing wrong?
